# In SQL how to pull through date of record and min date for a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data looks like the following;

```
| Location | ticketPeriod | UserID | ticketUses | Demographic |    Date    |
|----------|--------------|--------|------------|-------------|------------|
| London   | Day          |      1 |          1 | Adult       | 21/03/2019 |
| London   | Day          |      1 |          2 | Adult       | 06/02/2019 |
| Glasgow  | Day          |      1 |          1 | Adult       | 04/04/2019 |
| Glasgow  | Day          |     12 |          3 | Child       | 03/04/2019 |
| Glasgow  | Day          |      3 |          1 | Child       | 04/01/2019 |
| Glasgow  | Week         |      2 |          3 | Child       | 27/01/2019 |
| Glasgow  | Month        |      3 |          3 | Concession  | 04/04/2019 |
| London   | Annual       |      5 |          2 | Concession  | 15/02/2019 |
| London   | Quarterly    |      5 |          1 | Adult       | 13/02/2019 |
| Cardiff  | Annual       |      5 |          1 | Adult       | 24/01/2019 |
| Cardiff  | Quarterly    |      1 |          1 | Child       | 11/03/2019 |
| London   | Week         |      3 |          2 | Child       | 04/04/2019 |
| Cardiff  | Week         |     12 |          4 | Adult       | 04/04/2019 |
| London   | Annual       |      3 |          9 | Adult       | 04/04/2019 |
```

what I am trying to do is group the data to get minimum date and count ticketUse for each group but keep the date field, like the following;

```
| Location | ticketPeriod | UserID | ticketUses | Demographic |    Date    |  MinDate   | countTicketUses |
|----------|--------------|--------|------------|-------------|------------|------------|-----------------|
| Cardiff  | Annual       |      5 |          1 | Adult       | 24/01/2019 | 24/01/2019 |               1 |
| Cardiff  | Quarterly    |      1 |          1 | Child       | 11/03/2019 | 11/03/2019 |               1 |
| Cardiff  | Week         |     12 |          4 | Adult       | 04/04/2019 | 04/04/2019 |               4 |
| Glasgow  | Day          |      3 |          1 | Child       | 04/04/2019 | 04/01/2019 |               5 |
| Glasgow  | Day          |      3 |          3 | Child       | 03/04/2019 | 04/01/2019 |               5 |
| Glasgow  | Day          |      3 |          1 | Child       | 04/01/2019 | 04/01/2019 |               5 |
| Glasgow  | Week         |      2 |          3 | Child       | 27/01/2019 | 27/01/2019 |               6 |
| Glasgow  | Week         |      3 |          3 | Child       | 04/04/2019 | 27/01/2019 |               6 |
| London   | Day          |      1 |          1 | Adult       | 21/03/2019 | 06/02/2019 |              17 |
| London   | Day          |      1 |          2 | Adult       | 06/02/2019 | 06/02/2019 |              17 |
| London   | Day          |      5 |          2 | Adult       | 15/02/2019 | 06/02/2019 |              17 |
| London   | day          |      5 |          1 | Adult       | 13/02/2019 | 06/02/2019 |              17 |
| London   | day          |      3 |          2 | Adult       | 04/04/2019 | 06/02/2019 |              17 |
| London   | day          |      3 |          9 | Adult       | 04/04/2019 | 06/02/2019 |              17 |
```

Basically the equivalent of group by, mutate in R.

Comment: Would you please re-format a bit your datas ? As you can see, this is barely readable. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: how is `group` defined?

Comment: You can group by using Location and Ticket Period and get the minimum date and the counts in a separate temporary base and then update the same in the original table

Comment: A group is every field except the ticket Uses

Comment: Then your expected data is not correct as the last lines have different values for UserID and if that was included in the group, you would get a different output for e.g. the countTicketUses. And obviously you can't include the `Date` in the group either, otherwise the MinDate wouldn't make sense.

Comment: sorry about that, that is an error. those tables were made by hand just to present the issue

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select Location, 
       ticketPeriod,
       UserID, 
       ticketUses, 
       Demographic, 
       Date, 
       min(date) over (partition by ticketPeriod, Demographic) as MinDate, 
       sum(ticketUses) over (partition by ticketPeriod, Demographic) as countTicketUses 
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I was after :D